# The Exact time distance from button clicked to when received data to a website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

I'm creating a chrome extension. I need to know when a user clicked on a specific button how many mili seconds will take long, to receive that command to website server. I have a web Worker that is connected to that website too. Could I get the exact time when a button clicked to when data received by website's server? It doesn't matter how many mili seconds take that the respond back to me, the time of receiving request to server after click is mu issue now. can someone help me please?

I'm looking for javascript code to get the time distance between button clicked and received that by website's server.

Comment: try performance.now() method it will give you timestap.

Comment: where and how? consider that I'm writing in a postMessage event. Where should I put performance.now ti get the time that request arrived to server?

Comment: Sounds like what you need to do is have the server respond with when it got the request, then you can calculate the difference between that time and the sent time

Comment: To do that, you'll need to look at server's Apache access log.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst exactly... So without accessing to that server, how can I calculate it? Any suggestion?

Comment: @vahiDesigner creates an event listener on the button. then initialize the variable for start time for example var stime = performance.now(); then the request is sent you just need to calculate the time difference. as you know if the ready state equals 4 it's me the data loaded and uses the same variable with a differnt name like var etime = performance.now(); Now you have 2 variables just calculate the difference.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you don't have access to the server it's not possible. The solution others are suggesting would let you know how long it took the browser to actually send the request, but it would not let you know the time the server actually received it.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get the time when button is clicked by finding that button and attaching an event handler on it, that calls `performance.now()`

```
const t0 = 0;
document.getElementById('buttonId').addEventListener('click',() => {
  t0 = performance.now();
});
```

Detecting when the server response is received is not trivial. You might need to use the `chrome.webRequest` api.

Alternatively, a simpler way would be to look for side-effects of the request, that happen in the DOM. (A loader appearing and disappearing, data rows appearing, button being disabled and re-enabled, etc).

You can either poll for these changes, or use the `mutationObserver` api to detect when elements containing expected attributes are available in the DOM.

Let's say you are polling for the button being re-enabled, every 10ms:

```
const t1 = 0;
const interval = window.setInterval(() => {
  if (!document.getElementById('buttonId').getAttribute('disabled')) {
    t1 = performance.now();
    requestTime = t1 - t0;
    console.log(requestTime);
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
},10);
```